# Hide tooltip if empty in md-tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tooltip, angular-material

I have following tooltip:

```
<i ng-click="createDetails(item)" class="fa fa-info-circle">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
        {{item.details}}
    </md-tooltip>
</i>

$scope.createDetails = function (item) {
    item["details"] = "example";
}
```

If i click, details appears (tooltip is not centered, another problem but OK for now)

The main problem is: I want to hide the tooltip if there is no information, so when `item.details == undefined`

I tried ng-show, md-visible, ng-class etc. Is there a solution for these problem(s)?

Comment: How about `<md-tooltip md-direction="top" ng-show="item.details">` ?

Comment: i tried `ng-show` and it didn't work

Comment: `ng-if` will not create `DOM` if condition fails..And that could be the reason..

Comment: precisely! but still i most un-hover and hover again the tooltip to see the tooltip, which is actually not acceptable for users

Comment: I would like to work with the fiddle or codepen if you could provide..

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ng-if` to evaluate content of `item.details` variable to decide whether `<md-tooltip>` element is created or not.

```
<i ng-click="createDetails(item)" class="fa fa-info-circle">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="top" ng-if="item.details">
        {{item.details}}
    </md-tooltip>
</i>
```

Comment: i tried `ng-show ` instead of `ng-if` and it didn't work but surprisingly ng-if is working. However, you have to re-hover to the object to be able to see the tooltip. How can we solve this?

Comment: What you mean by re-hover? Anyway I don't know exactly [tag:angular-material], sorry

Comment: This solution provokes the tooltip doesn't appear in the right location.